# Accessing elements in a list in a Queryset

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I am saving a elements from a list from from a page on my Django site

The lists look like this when saved to the Database

```
['Precipitaciones', 'Pirineo', 'aragonés', 'catalán']
['activarán', 'tormentas', 'ibérica,', 'descartan', 'chubascos', 'dispersos,', 'temperaturas']
```

I want to be able to access all the elements but when I run a queryset with context I get returned

```
 <QuerySet [("['Precipitaciones', 'Pirineo', 'aragonés', 'catalán']",  ("['activarán', 'tormentas', 'ibérica,', 'descartan', 'chubascos', 'dispersos,', 'temperaturas']")]>
```

Which to me looks like a stings inside a list inside a string inside a tuple inside a Queryset.

So I can't workout how to access a single element

when I try → queryset.0.0

I have returned to the screen
[image]

Which returns the first element of the first element but I don't know how to get the first string of that element if I use → queryset.0.0.0 I just get the first element again which is a bracket **[**

Any help appreciated or some documentation where I can discover more about it would be great.

this is the queryset I'm using

```
queryset = model.objects.filter(show_word=True).values_list('word_esp').filter(username_id = user_id_fk)`
```

Comment: You need to show your code. How are you generating that?

Comment: Added the queryset that is generating it.

Answer (score 0):

you store your list as string in database. so queryset.0.0 is a string not list. and when you call queryset.0.0.0 returns first character in string `[`

you have two solution:

1- if your database backend is postgres you can use JSONField instead of using CharField os TextField

2- in your template you can write a filter to load string as json and get expected element like this:

```
@register.filter
def get_from_string_list(str_list, index):
    list_object = json.loads(str_list)
    return list_object[index]
```

and in your template use it like this:

```
{{ queryset.0.0|get_from_string_list:0 }}
```

in your python code you can convert selected string to json and get expected index

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, It's not a list in the Database it's a string. I'll try your recommendation.